# mongodb aggregate on huge dataset

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have a mongodb db with more than 100 millions documents. i want to do aggregation so i can give statistics on documents.
my document look like :

```
{
    "categ": "categ_4", 
    "code": 200, 
    "date": "01/01/2017", 
    "host": "www.myhost.com", 
    "hour": "19", 
    "http_ver": "HTTP/1.1", 
    "idate": 20170101, 
    "length": 21, 
    "protocol": "https", 
    "remote_ip": "111.22.333.44", 
    "resp_time": 0, 
    "time": "19:53:15", 
    "url": "my_url", 
}
```

when aggregating, i perform a query like this in my shell :

```
db.data.aggregate([{"$match": {"code":200}}, {"$group": {_id : "$code", total : {"$sum" : 1}}},{"$sort" : {_id: 1}}])
```

the problem is that it takes a very long time to compute. this is too slow. is there any way to speed up this operation ?
i tryed to create index on "code" field but with no success

```
db.data.createIndex({code:1})
```

what can I do to make aggregation faster ?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your query is same as

```
db.data.count({"code":200})
```

you don't need aggregation for that. Try simple count (with index)

Comment: my query was wrong (i had to remove the "$match" part). what i want to get is something like this :

`db.data.aggregate([{"$group": {_id : "$code", total : {"$sum" : 1}}},{"$sort"    : {total: 1}}])

    { "_id" : 404, "total" : 11729 }

    { "_id" : 302, "total" : 56068 }
   { "_id" : 410, "total" : 579872 }
   { "_id" : 304, "total" : 8201025 }
   { "_id" : 301, "total" : 1639247 }
   { "_id" : 200, "total" : 82234244 }
`

Comment: what do you mean by "Try simple count (**with index**)", is there an efficient way to add indexes to mongodb? as i said above, i tryed the createIndex function, but it don't seem to affect how aggregation work. i don't know how indexes works with mongodb, do you ?

Comment: @DanyM if find/count/$match query can use indexes, then it uses them instead of scanning each document in the collection (see [Indexes manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)). If your aggregation query don't start with $match step, then it will not use indexes.

Comment: @DanyM If your query is too slow, consider to reduce amount of data which should be processed. E.g. you can filter entries by date and get stats on daily/weekly/monthly basis instead of aggregating all collection.  (with index for date, and I would also recommend to have date field of Date type instead of string).

Comment: thank for you answer. OK, do i have to manually ad indexed to field i want to query (the same as mysql) ? or mongodb handle this by its own?

Comment: @DanyM by default mongo creates only index for _id field. Any other indexes you should add manually. E.g. `db.data.createIndex({date:-1})`